# Meaning of pound (#) in a regular expression

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression with a pound `#` modifier.

What does `\#` mean in a regular expression?  What does the `#` mean in a regular expression?  Is it possible that Java is just ignoring these invalid modifiers?

Comment: Isn't \ an escape character? Not sure the purpose of the # though.

Comment: It could originate from a PCRE regex that used `#` as delimiter.

Comment: Escaping can be done on anything even characters to that don't have any special meaning.  In my experience, it is not uncommon to see all sorts of things escaped because the writer of the regex was _not sure_ if the character had special meaning or not...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`\#` is not a valid regex modifier. It would technically be a way to escape a `#` character, IF the `#` meant anything significant in Java's regex. Because it doesn't, Java is just ignoring this invalidity and reading it as a `#` instead of throwing you an error.

Comment: [The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile(java.lang.String)) actually explains this: "It is an error to use a backslash prior to any alphabetic character that does not denote an escaped construct; these are reserved for future extensions to the regular-expression language. A backslash may be used prior to a non-alphabetic character regardless of whether that character is part of an unescaped construct."

Answer (score 2):

As you have suspected, it's just a mistake.

To be sure, I ran:

```
String quote = Pattern.quote("_#_");
```

and the output was:

```
"\Q_#_\E"
```

So, clearly, the pound symbol ("#") is not a special character for java regex.

See: [Pattern.quote()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 2):

I just had this same issue. It turned out that the prior programmer "missed" when changing all the "old code" from `#` to `|` and it was a simple mistake. I found this by checking all other code in the app and found NO other `#` symbols, but many similar areas of code with `|` included. And the `|` was right next to the `#` in this code. So someone was swapping out old regex for new regex and "missed".