# Meaning of the # (pound) symbol

Tags: java

Does Java provide any symbolic meaning to the `#` (pound) symbol? It appears to be a meaningless symbol.

I have seen it used as a pattern for [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html), but that is not the Java compiler giving it a meaning.

Comment: no it is not any special keyword other than used by some classes to define Pattern, its not like python comment character

Comment: it is just for pattern nothing else.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220492/meaning-of-pound-in-a-regular-expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java Language Specification contains several cases of the implicit translation by the compiler where the symbol `#` is used. For instance, from [§14.14.2. The enhanced for statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) :

> ```
> List<? extends Integer> l = ...
> for (float i : l) ...
> ```
>
> will be translated to:
>
> ```
> for (Iterator<Integer> #i = l.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
> float #i0 = (Integer)#i.next();
> ...
> ```
>
> `#i` is an automatically generated identifier that is distinct from any other identifiers (automatically generated or otherwise) that are in scope (§6.3) at the point where the enhanced `for` statement occurs.

It is unclear, if this is just a notation for the Specification purposes, or this describes actual internal details of the compiler (sometimes low-level implementation details are exposed in the JLS).

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't any special meaning given to the `#` symbol by the compiler. There are, however, special meanings for it when it is in a string that is used for a specific purpose, like you pointed out.